# Thunderbird trash always empty with Gmail account

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird, gmail

I have a Thunderbird email client connected to my Gmail account and the trash is always empty when I restart my computer.

This happens despite having set Thunderbird to not empty trash after closing.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Google is not like a regular IMAP server. Deleting mail does not "move it to trash" like most imap servers. Google doesn't publish the real Trash folder. You can only see it from web interface.